# What might solve OpenID's security problems

Tags: security, web-applications, authentication, openid

The problem I have with OpenID is how anyone can put up a form that looks like yahoo/google's form and direct users there and steel the passwords. This affects me as a user (though I can be careful about it), but it affects OpenID providers. What can be done to prevent this? Other than educating the users to look at the URL and all this. I mean a technical way to prevent this.

Comment: Phishing is a problem not unique to OpenID.

Comment: @ceejayoz, true but the consequences are unique when it's done on OpenID, with OpenID being a one login fits all type of login system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is called [Trusted Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_path) and there are few good solutions to it.  Ka-Ping Yee's thesis, linked in that wikipedia article includes a good treatment of it though.

Answer (score 3):

That essentially boils down to a phishing attack. This isn't something that can easily be prevented from a technical point of view, unless there's mutual agreements between all authentication partys involved. Some banks now show an image that the user selected. In effect, the bank is trying to prove that they are that actual bank (because they know what image you chose during registration) and the user is providing the bank with a password to show that they are authorized to access the account.

Comment: This extra image doesn't address MITM attacks.  An attacker can still put up a phishing page, and just forward the user's input to the real bank, get the image, and play it back to the user.

Comment: @Mike Samuel - No, it's not 100% secure (what is?) but it's one extra step in the prevention of phishing attacks. Advantage is, the bank can confirm suspcious activity much more easily because of the number of requests being made from one/multiple servers in an attempt to retrieve the user's image. Of course, this can be extended by checking the country the IP is originating from as well as having the bank emailing the user/texting for confirmation if the IP address is suspicious.

Comment: It can actually trivially be avoided, from a technical point of view, by using certificates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication

Comment: @keyboardP, If you use the banking examples, remember that the image is shown _after_ login credentials are given, so I'm really wondering if it's useful at all. Your "mutual agreements between all authentication partys involved" is very vague. I was thinking sites have to register with the OpenID provider, but again _before_ entering the login info, how does the user know if the site he's on is registered or not. That may be possible with a browser plugin or something, but it's now becoming not so different from the idea of a Password Manager

Comment: I would go with SSL certificated as I said before, because that way you know for sure that is your host. — But yes people need to learn and the browsers need to refuse the most popular websites (or the ones listed somewhere) without certificates.

Comment: @Noon Silk - I didn't say it wasn't possible. I said it requires mutual agreement from all authenticating partys (as stated in the article, most web apps don't require client-side certificates). @sameold My bank shows the image after I've entered my username, but before my password. Not perfect, but better than confirming post- password entry :)

Comment: @keyboardP: Obviously you didn't say it wasn't possible, you said it wasn't easy. I said it was.

Comment: @Noon Silk - I said it wasn't easy, *unless* there's mutual agreement :)

Comment: @sameold, if the bank waits until receiving both username _and_ password, then you're right, it is silly and useless. But at least http://www.vanguard.com/ asks for username, _then_ shows the security image when asking for the password. It is a little strange, but I for one am glad they took this issue seriously years ago...

Comment: @keyboardP True, you've got me here, didn't see that, my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

One idea I've always liked (not only because it's my idea), is that you can solve this problem by never allowing the user to have their own password. The strategy would be that, to log in, the user visits the website they want to log in to, and requests an authentication token. The token is then emailed to them, valid for a little bit, and they just click the link to log in.

The obvious problems to this, approach, though, are that: Your email can't do it. So, it's shifting the problem slightly. But, if you authenticate with your email provider, or whoever, via the client-side certificate approach: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication, and give some other things a bit of thought (i.e. ensuring transmission of the details of the login link aren't intercepted, etc), it's at the very least "interesting" to think about.

But, in general, the way to solve your problem is: authenticate both sides of the transaction; i.e. ensure that the website you are talking to is the one you want, before sending it anything you care about.

Comment: A different token for each website would be great in many situations because you wouldn't be trusting your "password" to anyone... it's like the twitter or ebay tokens ;) Mutual authentication is bringing a VPN to the party... very "expensive".

Comment: @Noon Silk, If I understood you correctly, this doesn't involve OpenID at all. Now, the obvious problem I see with this is that someone who has temporary access to your email can request the access token. This means that you have to keep track of requests of access tokens (just like a credit card bill does) to let the user know when accesses were made. The user then looks at it every so often and checks for requests not made by him. But if the user uses a site often, it's hard to remember if they wanted to login on Saturday at 11:17am or that was the girlfriend messing around with my account.

Comment: @someold: True, having access to email suddenly becomes "very important", but it's currently that way, anywway (you can request password resets which only require an email address, generally, and maybe other trivial information). Once inside, actions can also be authenticated (dependin on what it is, bank transfers are limited to authorised accounts, for small amounts, etc, etc, banks do this already).

Comment: @Noon Silk, The other problem with this as you said is depending on email. It requires the extra step that I have to check my email. If that's the case, I could also use the password reset feature every time I want to login.

Comment: @someold: Indeed. Checking email is almost never a problem, though, when you want to log in to something. Remember - this isn't neccessarily more convenient (in a way it is, because it means you don't need to *remember* the password, you can't remember what you don't have). The idea was to stop the user being able to be phished (i.e. by knowing something and typing it in the wrong place). The idea removes this knowledge from them; and keeps their knowledge to a minimum. Which is good, for preventing phishing. (Infact, ideal).

Comment: @Noon Silk, OK, someone has temporary access to the user's email. They can either (a) request access token as you suggest or (b) request to reset the password. If (a), I just described the whole "credit card statement" analogy and how the user might not be able to really tell if requests were made by him. If (b), the user automatically knows the next time he tries to log in that his password was reset without his knowledge, or at least that something fishy has happened. So I still see your solution as not very safe. In the case of email compromise, your solution has more dangers.

Comment: @sameold: Arguable, practically, but your point is somewhat legitimate. I leave it to you to analyse the threats fully for your specific requirements.

Comment: @Noon Silk, I do grant you though that the account can't be phished by sites. Just wanted to point out the risk of being phished from the inside by people who can request such token if they gain temp access to your email.

Comment: @sameold: Yes, it's not "phished" though, then, it's that your email account was just logged in to by an unauthorised user. As i said, it increases the "value" of the email address, but perhaps not significantly more than it already is (and as I mentioned above, the risk is lower because banks and other items of interest should have internal additional measures *once authenticated* to prevent too much harm occuring).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into the openID authentication protocol but SSL (is the way to go, it) makes the website trustable and the browsers should really start to have like lists of websites like google, yahoo, youtube, facebook etc that use that technology and refuse to open the website without getting the proper certificate first.

Thats a solution that goes a little bit beyond the scope of your problem but also solves it. Because think about this... if StackOverflow starts using SSL why the browser should allow connections to it without getting a proper certificate first? Make sense right?

One single technology, all the problems solved.